What is the operating frequency of the 8085 in the System/23 Datamaster computer?
What should be the frequency read at pin 1 of the CPU of this IBM computer?

I asked and self-replied in order to introduce data, so when you search you could find it and stop giving the 5150 frequency. Is there any justification for the downvotes? If so, please write it so I can improve it.

The master clock in Datamaster motherboards is a 18.432MHz oscillator, which is divided by 3 and supplied to the processor. Therefore the correct answer would be 6.14MHz, 33% duty cycle. However, it should be stated that the 8085 also divides its input clock by 2 and therefore its effective operating frequency would be 3.07MHz.

So you're saying that the Wikipedia article is wrong?

Correct. I took the information from my unit, checked with another two Datamasters whose owners I am helping. There was a gap in the data so they filled it with information from the 5150 PC.

@DaveTweed The article simply quotes some external page, which provides the apparently wrong frequency.

But the issue is that the data is difficult to fact-check due to the low number of units remaining. This has been contrasted and found to be wrong. Not only do I have a unit but I am also studying it, please take this opportunity to amend old misunderstandings. Sometimes answers are not in the papers but in the hardware. I also found errors in the service manual too (in other areas).

@thebusybee if you are referring to bitspassats.com, there is the correct frequency. Actually that place is where I do post my own research.

No, the Wikipedia article reference #8 points to https://www.oldcomputers.es/ibm-systems23-5322/ for its statement on the frequency.

The problem with Wikipedia is that they do not allow "original research". You would have to write a paper that you publish separately, and then reference that from the Wikipedia article.

Wikipedia and its sources are an issue which is unrelated to the reason I inputted this. I made it to improve the quality of the answers here. Understandably, there are very few things about the System/23, but are answers like the following which made me post. https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/22262/23759
